# None type json object after hosting in Apache server

Tags: python, json, apache, flask, postman

I have a python script that is hosted on a python flask server.

When I test it with postman by providing Json in the body of postman, I get very good response. But when I try using the same method after hosting the same script in apache server, I am getting a `Nontype for my json.request`. Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 0):

I was accepting both `GET and POST methods in my flask script`

I changed `@app.route('/my_url',methods=["GET","POST"])`

to `@app.route('/my_url',methods=["POST"])`